# Jquery image resize doesn't work constantly

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery to resize image. It works fine just some time it fires width and height zero value.
Here is my code.
Do you guys have any idea why returns zero to its width & height.

This is the jquery code that I am using

```
//Image Popup viewer
    function imgViewerLoad() {
        $(".imageViewer").fadeIn("slow");
        var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        var ivHeight = $(".imageViewer").height();
        var ivWidth = $(".imageViewer").width();
            $(".imageViewer").css({
                "position": "absolute",
                "width": ivWidth,
                "min-width": ivWidth,
                "height": ivHeight,
                "left": (windowWidth/2-ivWidth/2)-53,
                "top": windowHeight/2-ivHeight/2
            });
        //After Load the image
        $(".imageViewer .loading-big").show();
        $(".imgPreview").load(function() {
            $(".loading-big").hide();

            //Added resize function for large image
            //Set max image size 90% of the window
            var max_w1 = ($(window).width()*90)/100;
            var max_h1 = ($(window).height()*90)/100;

            var this_w1 = $(".imgPreview").width();
            var this_h1 =$(".imgPreview").height();
            if(this_w1==0){this_w1=500}//if width==0 then refer to window fit size
            if(this_w1==0){this_w1=500}//if width==0 then refer to window fit size

            //Set back to its original size if new size exceed its original size
            if(max_w1 > this_w1) max_w1 = this_w1;
            if(max_h1 > this_h1) max_h1 = this_h1;

            if (this_w1/this_h1 < max_w1/max_h1) {
            var h1 = max_h1;
            var w1 = Math.ceil(max_h1/this_h1 * this_w1);
            } else {
            var w1 = max_w1;
            var h1 = Math.ceil(max_w1/this_w1 * this_h1);
            }
            $(".imgPreview").css({ height: h1, width: w1 });
            //End resizing

            $(this).fadeIn('slow');
            $(".nav .right").hide();//Hide Main Nav next prev
            $(".nav .imgViewNav").show();//Show image viewer next prev
            //Center image viewer
            var ivHeight1 = $(".imgPreview").height();
            var ivWidth1 = $(".imgPreview").width();
            $(".imageViewer").css({
                "position": "absolute",
                "width": ivWidth1,
                "min-width": ivWidth1,
                "height": ivHeight1,
                "left": (windowWidth/2-ivWidth1/2)-53,
                "top": windowHeight/2-ivHeight1/2
            });
        });
        $(".overLay").stop().fadeTo('slow',0.55).height(windowHeight);
    }

    //Load light box when clicked on thumbnail
    $('.secondary .imgWrapper').on('click',function() {//Touchend is for touch screen like ipad
           $(".imgPreview").remove();//Remove image viewer if exist
           //$(".imageViewer").append('<img src="'+ colorPath+ 'large/' + num +'.jpg" id="'+ num + '"/>');
           getImgPath = $(this).children('.iColor').attr('src');
           imgId = $(this).children('.iColor').attr('id');
           //$(".imageViewer").append('<img src="'+ colorPath+ num +'.jpg" id="'+ num + '"/>');

           newUrl = getImgPath.substring(0, getImgPath.lastIndexOf("."));//Remove extension
           finalUrl = newUrl.replace(/[0-9]+/g,'');//Remove number

           $(".imageViewer").append('<img src="'+ finalUrl + 'large/' + imgId +'.jpg" id="'+ imgId +'" class="imgPreview" />');

            //Load Image viewer function
            imgViewerLoad();

        });


    $('.next').click(function() {

        var getImgSrc = $(".imgPreview").attr('src');
        var getImgId = $(".imgPreview").attr('id');
        nextId = getImgId+++1;
        remExt = getImgSrc.substring(0, getImgSrc.lastIndexOf("."));//Remove extension
        remNum = remExt.replace(/[0-9]+/g,'');//Remove number

        //Declear var for total images on each page
        if($(".port").hasClass('Active')) {
            lastImg = 61;
        } else if($(".advs").hasClass('Active')) {
            lastImg = 43;
        }
        if(getImgId < lastImg) {//Disable click if this is last image
            $(".imgPreview").remove();//Remove image viewer if exist
            $(".imageViewer").removeAttr('style');
            $(".imageViewer").append('<img src="'+ remNum+nextId +'.jpg" id="'+ nextId +'" class="imgPreview" />');

            //Load Image viewer function
            imgViewerLoad();
        }

    })
    $('.prev').click(function(e) {
        var getImgSrc = $(".imgPreview").attr('src');
        var getImgId = $(".imgPreview").attr('id');
        nextId = getImgId-1;
        remExt = getImgSrc.substring(0, getImgSrc.lastIndexOf("."));//Remove extension
        remNum = remExt.replace(/[0-9]+/g,'');//Remove number

        if(getImgId > 1) { //Disable click if this is first image
        //$(".imgPreview").attr({'src': remNum+nextId+ '.jpg', 'id': nextId }); 

        $(".imgPreview").remove();//Remove image viewer if exist
        $(".imageViewer").attr('style','');
        $(".imageViewer").append('<img src="'+ remNum+nextId +'.jpg" id="'+ nextId +'" class="imgPreview" />');

        //Load Image viewer function
            imgViewerLoad();
        }
    })

    function hideImageViewer() {
        $('div.nav').addClass('stayOn').removeClass('stayOff');//Add class to nav
        $('.overLay').stop().fadeTo('slow',0).delay(1000).hide();
        $("div.imageViewer").hide().attr('style','z-index: 299; display:none;');
        $(".nav .right").show();
        $(".nav .imgViewNav").hide();
    }

    //Close Image viewer
    $('.overLay').click(function() {
        hideImageViewer();
    })
    $('.close').click(function() {
        hideImageViewer();
    });
```

And html code

Comment: My initial thought is, are you waiting until the images load to determine their dimension?

Comment: Yes it runs inside load function `$(".imgPreview").load(function() {//Run resize});`

Comment: What you've posted either seems unrealistic or wrong, in the sense of `$("img")`. Please post a Short, Self Contained, Correct \(Compilable\), Example, eg: http://sscce.org/.